# Ruby gem to obscure data

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Anyone know of a gem that will allow you to obscure/sanitize data?

Usecase: Download a production database, run some sanitation so that real customers won't get emails, cards charged etc.

Comment: I think the verb you are looking for is anonymization.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [forgery](http://github.com/sevenwire/forgery) gem to replace the content of sensitive fields with randomly generated data.